# Flickering fixed background during transition

Tags: css, transition, fixed, flicker, translate3d

I'm having problem on my fixed background during transition. I have 2 panels, the panel-1 has 2 images which will animate from left to right and from right to left respectively, basically it will just add a class 'animate' to trigger the transition. During the transition, the panel-2 (which has the **fixed background** and some text contents) will flickers in chrome. Kindly check it live http://jsfiddle.net/7EqaV/embedded/result/

Any advice? Thanks in advance!..

HTML code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<input type="button" value='animate' id="animate" />
<div class="panel-1">
    <div class="items" id="slideLeft">
        <img src="http://sitetest12302.businesscatalyst.com/images/p1.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="items" id="slideRight">
        <img src="http://sitetest12302.businesscatalyst.com/images/p2.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel-2">
    <div class="bg"></div>
    <div class="content">
            <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna</h1>

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
    .wrapper {
    width:500px;
    margin:auto;
}
.panel-1, .panel-2 {
    width:100%;
    height: 200px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    position:relative;
}
.panel-2 .bg {
    width:100%;
    height: 200px;
    background:url(http://sitetest12302.businesscatalyst.com/images/bg.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    position: absolute;
    background-position:center;
}
.items {
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
}
.content {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
    width:100%;
}
h1 {
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);
    -moz-opacity:0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:15px;
}
#slideLeft, #slideRight {
    -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 1s 0s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s 0s;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
}
#slideLeft {
    float:left;
    -webkit-transform:translate3d(-200%, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform:translate3d(-200%, 0, 0);
}
#slideRight {
    float:right;
    -webkit-transform:translate3d(200%, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform:translate3d(200%, 0, 0);
}
.animate #slideLeft, .animate #slideRight {
    -webkit-transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.animate h1 {
    filter:alpha(opacity=100) !important;
    -moz-opacity:1 !important;
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input#animate').click(function () {
        $('.panel-1, .panel-2').toggleClass('animate');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Heello!

Try use this css:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
/*  will not work for sprites and image backgrounds */

body {-webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);}
/* screws up backgrounds that are tiled  */
```

I suppose to you make a class called noflick and this css

```
.noflick{-webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);}
```

I hope this will help you.